# Get a DVD onto my iPhone

Tags: iphone, dvd

Is there an official way to take my DVD and put it on my iPhone?

Comment: Please clarify what "offical" means to you. I'll assume you mean a commercially available and supported product.

Comment: Well, I was hoping there was an apple solution.  Failing that I will take whatever is normally used by the community.

Comment: I trust by *official* you actually mean *legal*.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There isn't an "official" way but a common and easy method is to rip the DVD with a utility like [HandBrake](http://handbrake.fr/) and then drop it in iTunes to sync with your iPhone. The US Supreme Court ruled that

> nothing in the agreement prevents you
>   from making copies of DVDs. Nothing
>   requires that a DVD be present during
>   playback.

So yes, it is legal. [source](http://yro.slashdot.org/story/07/04/29/1913251/Kaleidescape-Triumphant-in-Court-Case-DVD-Ripping-Ruled-Legal)

Comment: Good point; I'm not an American and I tend to forget about that court decision. I've deleted my earlier answer.

Comment: I'd point out that that ruling only applies in the US. Any international users who read this would be advised to consult their own lawyers first about the legality.

Comment: Apparently more than HandBreak is needed.  I ran it on my DVD and it was filled with all kinds of artifacts/noise and the audio was choppy.

Comment: @Vaccano I don't have a lot of experience using HandBrake since I don't own DVDs, but a lot of people on the EiC forum swear by it. Maybe a tutorial will help? http://www.everythingicafe.com/forum/threads/tutorial-put-your-dvds-on-your-iphone-step-by-step-instructions.6047/

Comment: Two awesome [alternatives](http://alternativeto.net/software/handbrake/?platform=mac) to the great Handbrake: [Adapter](http://www.macroplant.com/adapter/) and [the discontinued but still great iSquint](http://www.techspansion.com/)

Answer (score 3):

Actually, it's pretty straight forward.

[image]

Comment: Hilarious, and technically a valid answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend the program [RipIt](http://thelittleappfactory.com/ripit/) by [the little app factory](http://thelittleappfactory.com/) if by official you mean a commercially available and supported software to accomplish the task of ripping a commercial DVD into a format that will work with iTunes to play DVD content on iOS. There are free solutions, but I prefer paying for an interface and a manual and most of all, support and someone paid to develop new fixes to the ripping software when new discs come out with different tricks to prevent ripping. (It's a game of cat and mouse between the movie studios and the rippers unfortunately.)

The company is very responsive in supporting its customers and has been around for some time. Well worth the money for the time and aggravation it saves me. Their passport bundle is a great value if you will use more than two of their products.

If you want legal advice whether doing this is wise, do check with a local lawyer.

Answer (score 0):

The best, and also a very legal, way to go would be Handbrake (as styfle says), however many DVDs come now with a digital copy, where you get a code which can be used to download a copy for iTunes (full DRM so only in iTunes), from there you can sync it to your iPhone. This method is probably easier for a non-techie (although Handbrake is pretty simple), but it's a lot more restricting.